# CSS transform - Simulating a camera, moving the y axis along the panning axis and keeping the center of pan axis

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a 3d "stage" for a game. I have several wrapped `div`s that i wrap to create different axis to move a center div with some content.

The problem is the pan- and Y axis. Y has to move along the Pan rotation so that moving the "camera" forward moves it along the axis of the pan. But moving the Y axis creates a distance from the center of the Pan `div` meaning that any panning with a value on Y will make the center of the pan rotation further and further away. I need to solve it so that I can move Y (`transform: translateY();`) along the axis of the panned (`transform: rotateX()`) wrapper and keep the center of the y axis on the pan, so that any panning wont put the y axis on a leverage.

I have this set up with Angular6 and Typescript where I can move the axis with input from mouse movement.

The closest solution i can come up with is using the same wrapper for both yAxis and Pan, but using `rotateX` and `translateY` on the same element doesn't work as it uses the original position for the `translateY`

The values for moving the camera is controlled in javascript where i have `moveX`, `moveY`, and `Pan`. As well as `zoom` and `rotate`, I don't think the last two are relevant, but I can obviously change all of these as i wish.

Extra: image from my project for further explanation https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rgex.jpg

Fiddle with example: https://jsfiddle.net/tdrsy6v9/

Code form fiddle:

HTML

```
<div class="level-wrapper plane-a" id="gridWrapper">
  <div class="level-wrapper plane-b"> <!--zoom -->
    <div class="level-wrapper plane-c"> <!-- X axis -->
      <div class="level-wrapper plane-d"> <!-- pan -->
        <div class="level-wrapper plane-e"> <!-- y axis -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#gridWrapper {
    height: 300px;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    perspective: 800px;    
    border: 1px solid #525252;
    box-shadow: #ccc 0px 4px 8px 8px; 

}

.level-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; 
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    width:50px;
    height:50px
}

.plane-a {
  background: white;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.plane-b {
  background: green;
  transform: translateZ(-25px);
}

.plane-c {
  background: blue;
  transform: translateX(70px);
}

.plane-d {
  background: yellow;
  transform: rotateX(45deg)
}

.plane-e {
  background: purple;
  transform: translateY(70px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set transform-origin property? take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp)

Comment: Hmm, doing something like 'transform-origin': '0 ' + camera.moveY  + 'px' on the Pan div so that the origin increases as the Y value increases, offsets the rotation point to the right position, but counteracts changes to the value of the Y axis.. so it is a step in the right direction